# How to reduce the balance of a smart contract in Solidity

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.13;
contract TransferMoney{
  
uint public receivedBalance;
function ReceiveMoney() public payable{
   receiedBalance+=msg.value;
}
function ShowContractBalance() public view returns(uint){
   return address(this).balance/10**18;
}
function ShowContractBalance(address payable toAccount, uint amount) public{
   toAccount.transfer(address(this).balance-amount);
}
```

}

When I write this code and complete a transaction, the balance value is set to 0 even if I give the amount value as for instance 3 for a received value of 5. What is the problem? How can I reduce the balance of a smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

Change your smart contract code with this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.13;

contract TransferMoney {  
    uint public receivedBalance;

    function ReceiveMoney() public payable{
        receivedBalance += msg.value;
    }

    function ShowContractBalance() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function ShowContractBalance(address payable toAccount, uint amount) public{
        toAccount.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```